# How to prevent close of JFrame while closing JasperViewer

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How can I prevent close of *JFrame* while closing *JasperViewer*?

```
try {
          JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load("D:\\Projects\\DiagonosisCentre\\reports\\reportAddNewPatient.jrxml");
          String sqlr = "SELECT * FROM current where patientID = '"+id+"'";
          JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
          newQuery.setText(sqlr);
          jd.setQuery(newQuery);
          JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
          JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, db.conn);
          JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
     } catch (JRException jRException) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "catch 1"+jRException);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
```

Add this:

```
JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);
```